# numpy: how to calculate jacobian matrix

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix

I made an example of the dot product of two matrices, and I want to calculate the jacobian matrix of this dot product. The first matrix has a shape of 4x3, and the second matrix has the shape 2x4. The resulting jacobian matrix should have a shape of (4x3x2x3) because I am calculating it w.r.t the first matrix.

So lets say each element of the jacobian matrix is DiDjAkAl, that element would represent the partial derivative of the i,j output w.r.t the k,l input. Here's the example in code:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [5,6,7,8],
              [9,10,11,12]])
#shape = (4x3)

b = np.array([[1,2],
              [3,4],
              [5,6],
              [7,8]])
#shape = (2x4)

dotProduct = A.dot(b)
#shape = (2x3)
```

So basically my question is how to find the jacobian of that dot product.

Comment: can use [Autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md), or developed (based on it) JAX (jnp is slower than numpy, but has jit class - Just-In-Time compiler increasing speed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your solution, we can see that Indexes `i` and `k` are always the same value, therefore that for loop can be removed. Then the first for loop can be assign all in one go, using a list as slice. Concretely:

```py
def vect_jacobian(A,b):

    dotProduct = A.dot(b)
    ans = np.zeros((A.shape[0], A.shape[1], dotProduct.shape[0], dotProduct.shape[1]))
    L = list(range(A.shape[0]))
    ans[L,:,L,:] = b
    return ans

r = vect_jacobian(A,b)
```

Using `%timeit` in my local machine, we can see that even with these small size matrices, there is a 3x time improvement:

```
%timeit jacobian(A,b)
29.6 µs ± 3.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit vect_jacobian(A,b)
10.4 µs ± 589 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: @JamesB I think you can start from [arrays indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0021-advanced-indexing.html).
Please consider accepting the answer as indicated here [accepting-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick answer to what I'm looking for, but it uses for loops. Anyone who can help me vectorise this function would be of great help to me.

```
def jacobian(A, b):
    dotProduct = A.dot(b)
    ans = np.zeros((A.shape[0], A.shape[1], dotProduct.shape[0], dotProduct.shape[1]))
    for l in range(A.shape[0]):
        i = 0
        for k in range(A.shape[1]):
            ans[l][k][l][:] = b[i][:]
            i = i + 1
    return ans
```